# About Data from TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, dataset, memory-safety

I made a function that copies the Data from A TClientDataSet to B.

In production, the code will dynamically fill a TClientDataSet, like the following:

```
procedure LoadClientDataSet(const StringSql: String; ParamsAsArray: array of Variant; CdsToLoad: TClientDataSet);
begin
  //There is a shared TClientDataSet that retrieves 
  //all data from a TRemoteDataModule in here.

  //the following variables (and code) are here only to demonstration of the algorithm;
  GlobalMainThreadVariable.SharedClientDataSet.CommandText := StringSql;
  //Handle Parameters
  GlobalMainThreadVariable.SharedClientDataSet.Open;


  CdsToLoad.Data:= GlobalMainThreadVariable.SharedClientDataSet.Data;

  GlobalMainThreadVariable.SharedClientDataSet.Close; 
end;
```

That said:

- It is safe to do so? (By safe I mean, what kind of exceptions should I expect and how to deal with them?)
- How do I release ".Data's" memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data storage residing behind the Data property is reference counted. Therefore you don't have to bother releasing it.

If you want to dive deeper into the intrinsics of TClientDataSet I recommend reading the really excellent book from Cary Jensen: [Delphi in Depth: ClientDataSets](http://www.jensendatasystems.com/cdsbook/)

Answer (score 1):

By assigning the `Data` property like you did duplicates the records. You have now two different isntances of `TClientDataset` with two different set of records with precisely the same structure, same row count and same field values.

It´s safe to do that if the receiving `TClientDataset` does not have any field structure previously defined or the existing structure is compatible with the `Data` being assigned. However, if we are talking about a huge number of records, the assignment may take long time and, in an extreme circumstance, it could exaust the computer´s memory (it all the depends on the computer´s configuration).

In order to release the Data, just close the dataset.

If you prefer to have two instances of `TClientDataset` but one single instance of the records, my suggestion is to use the [`TClientDataset.CloneCursor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.CloneCursor) method, that instead of copying the Data, just assign a reference to it in a different dataset. In this case it´s the very same Data shared between two different datasets.

Comment: +1. Thank you for addressing `It is safe to do so? (By safe I mean, what kind of exceptions should I expect and how to deal with them?)`. I accepted @UweRaabe Answer because he answered first and explained that Data is reference counted. This matters because there are cases where `.Data` is not assigned to any DataSet.